# OPENSTACK SWIFT : org.javaswift.joss.exception.CommandException: Unable to open input stream for uploading

Tags: openstack, file-handling, openstack-swift

I'm able to connect to the account, I was also able to create and access a container too. But when I try to upload a object using the JOSS library I get the exception below. Does the file name has to be a file on local machine where the code is executed? I thought that would be the filename on the server where it will be stored under a particular container.

```
// Source Code
    public void addObject(String containerName,String objectName,String object) {
        Container container = account.getContainer(containerName);
        StoredObject storedObject = container.getObject(object);
        storedObject.uploadObject(new File(objectName));
    }

// TestCode
@Test
    public void testAddObject() {
        SwiftHandlerFactory instance = SwiftHandlerFactory.getInstance();
        SwiftHandler handler = null;
        try {
            handler = instance.getSwiftHandler(SwiftHandlerType.SwiftJossHandler, propertiesFile);
            handler.addObject("test_container", "/test_object", "Some random data");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

org.javaswift.joss.exception.CommandException: Unable to open input stream for uploading
    at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.object.UploadObjectCommandImpl.<init>(UploadObjectCommandImpl.java:29)
    at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.factory.StoredObjectCommandFactoryImpl.createUploadObjectCommand(StoredObjectCommandFactoryImpl.java:63)
    at org.javaswift.joss.client.core.AbstractStoredObject.directlyUploadObject(AbstractStoredObject.java:203)
    at org.javaswift.joss.client.core.AbstractStoredObject.uploadObject(AbstractStoredObject.java:146)
    at org.javaswift.joss.client.core.AbstractStoredObject.uploadObject(AbstractStoredObject.java:215)
    at com.ebay.swift.handler.joss.SwiftJossHandler.addObject(SwiftJossHandler.java:63)
    at com.ebay.swift.handler.joss.SwiftJossHandlerTest.testAddObject(SwiftJossHandlerTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\test_object (The specified path is invalid)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.getContent(FileEntity.java:95)
    at org.javaswift.joss.instructions.UploadPayloadFile.getEtag(UploadPayloadFile.java:30)
    at org.javaswift.joss.instructions.UploadInstructions.getEtag(UploadInstructions.java:136)
    at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.object.UploadObjectCommandImpl.prepareUpload(UploadObjectCommandImpl.java:38)
    at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.object.UploadObjectCommandImpl.<init>(UploadObjectCommandImpl.java:27)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The uploadObject had many variation, I was trying to upload a string here but it was trying to find a file on my local disk. I changed it to use the other method which uses byte[].

```
public void addObject(String containerName,String objectName,String object) {
    Container container = account.getContainer(containerName);
    if(!container.exists())
        container.create();
    StoredObject storedObject = container.getObject(objectName);
    storedObject.uploadObject(object.getBytes());
}
```